# Wireframe material node not working in Blender 2.83 or 2.9?

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

Alright, Im using the wireframe node to mix two Principled shaders in a material. This has worked in the past with eevee and 2.8 - suddenly in 2.83 and 2.9, I just get a black material when I use wireframe node.

Has wireframe been phased out / is there a fix for this?

Comment: Wireframe is still working for 2.9. You may have another issue.

Comment: Hello, please post a screenshot of your setup so we can evaluate what's wrong